# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: fsmDS not bound

Tags: java, spring, jndi, jboss5.x

I am migrating my spring jsf project from ANT to maven, while deploying in jboss 5 server getting below error.
 ERROR [ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'propertyLoaderJob' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/property.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'propertyloader' while setting bean property 'targetObject'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'propertyloader' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/property.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/DataSource.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: fsmDS not bound

Answer (score 0):

The exception means that JDBC driver is missed.Please check if you have JDBC driver dependency in pom.xml.